# Windows Server Essentials 2016 to Standard upgrade

Tags: windows, licensing, upgrade, file-server, workgroup

We installed Server Essentials 2016. Essentials requires the server to be DC. We don't use the domain, we only use it as a file server. Can we do an in-place update to Server Standard R2 and not use a domain at all?

Comment: When you say server standard R2, do you mean Server 2008 R2 or Server 2012 R2? If yes then it is not possible and that would be called a downgrade. You can upgrade versions if you use essentials and want to upgrade to standard or data center. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/installation-and-upgrade for more details.